# Объект «Snake» не имеет атрибута «PyGame»

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Control:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True
        self.direction = 'RIGHT'

    def control(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.flag = False
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    self.direction = 'RIGHT'
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    self.direction = 'LEFT'
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    self.direction = 'UP'
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    self.direction = 'DOWN'
class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 250
    def move(self, control):
        if control.direction == 'RIGHT':
            self.x += 25
        elif control.direction == 'LEFT':
            self.x -= 25
        elif control.direction == 'UP':
            self.y -= 25
        elif control.direction == 'DOWN':
            self.y += 25
    def draw(self, win):
        self.pygame.draw.rect(win, pygame.Color('Green'), pygame.Rect(x, y, 25, 25))

pygame.init()
control = Control()
snake = Snake()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('Змейка')

while control.flag:
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    control.control()
    snake.draw(win)
    snake.move(control)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/SnakeTurtle/main.py", line 48, in <module>
          snake.draw(win)
  File "D:/SnakeTurtle/main.py", line 37, in draw
    self.pygame.draw.rect(win, pygame.Color('Green'), pygame.Rect(x, y, 25, 25))
```

AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'pygame'

Comment: Не рекомендую отвечать этому товарищу, он потом удаляет вопросы с ответами. Так было уже минимум три раза.

Comment: 1) 2 раза 2) Я удалял свои первые вопросы когда только зарегался, ничего не понимал и только начал изучать python! Я даже не знал что  не принято удалять вопросы

Comment: @Эникейщик 2 раза. Но можно списать на незнание правил.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Да, видимо, два. Один, про который я думал, на месте.

Comment: Ладно, рискну 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убери `self.` из этой строчки

```
self.pygame.draw.rect(win, pygame.Color('Green'), pygame.Rect(x, y, 25, 25))
```